# Vscode Dev Container build with astro error

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, airflow, vscode-devcontainer

I'm trying to build/open a project in dev container using vscode. When I do reopen in container I get below error as shown in Image
[image]

Below are the steps I tried.
Added below cmd to dockerfile.
COPY packages.txt /packages.txt.
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
**Reinstalled VScode**

**System Config**
Windows 11 Home
VS code Details
Version: 1.86.1 (user setup)
Commit: 31c37ee8f63491495ac49e43b8544550fbae4533
Date: 2024-02-07T09:08:20.941Z
Electron: 27.2.3
ElectronBuildId: 26495564
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621

**Docker Version**
Docker Desktop 4.27.2 (137060)